# Setting a title to a custom dialog box

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom dialog box extending the `DialogFragment` class. As stated in the Androïd developer's guide, I have set the style and theme of my dialog. I use the `DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL` style, which, I suppose, authorizes to set a title to the box. This seems confirmed by the fact that a style called `DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE` exists.

The problem is I can't find any function to set this title.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `getDialog().setTitle("My Dialog Title")` to set the title

Answer (score 0):

I think you could call `getDialog()` to get the contained `Dialog` instance, then call `setTitle` on that with the required title.

A bit of a guess, since I'm not an Android developer.